# java how to simulate node.js req.send and req.query

Tags: java, node.js

I have a code for a web service in node.js and I want to do the same in java

This is the code in node js

```
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {

    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);

});
```

I want to make a similar on in java.

so my question what is `req.query[]` represents? is it a value for a

1. Query string
2. Form string
3. Other body values?

and what happens when sending by `send` function? it is a value in the body?

#### Update

i can see that `req.query` is a query parameter, but why there's dot ? how to receive it with dot? i can receive query parameters without dot, but with dot i am not able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you have is getting a query parameter from a URL like `http://example.org/webhook?hub.challenge=foo`; since Javascript uses dots to separate attributes, you cannot use `req.query.hub.challenge`, because there is no `hub` query parameter. The bracket notation is looking up a literal `hub.challenge` attribute name.

For more information on the nodejs objects, here's a [link to documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

For your question on `send`, the nodejs code is telling the response object to send an HTTP 200 (aka OK) response, with the body containing the value of the `hub.challenge` query parameter. In the example URL, that would mean the response body would be `foo`.